# Is it possible to 'expect' a method from a partial mock

Tags: ocmock

It is not the best thing to do, but I would like to verify that a private method of an object is called, so I create a partial mock and add an expectation on the private method.

```
Synchronizer * sync = [[Synchronizer alloc] initWithCleanup:YES];

sync = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:sync];
[[(id)sync expect] cleanupPreviousContents];
```

When I run the test, cleanupPreviousContents is not called but the test is still successful. Where is the bug ?

Regards,
Quentin

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is a perfectly valid thing to do. But you need to create a new reference for your partial mock:

```
Synchronizer * sync = [[Synchronizer alloc] initWithCleanup:YES];

id mockSync = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:sync];
[[mockSync expect] cleanupPreviousContents];  

... do something

[mockSync verify];
```

Is `cleanupPreviousContents` called within your `initWithCleanup` method? If so, you'll have to structure it a bit differently:

```
Synchronizer *sync = [Synchronizer alloc];

id mockSync = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:sync];
[[mockSync expect] cleanupPreviousContents];  

[sync initWithCleanup:YES];

[mockSync verify];
```